# Long job title name does not fit into border

Tags: bug, design, sidebar, stack-overflow-jobs

As described in the title I saw a job in the "Looking For a Job?" section with a pretty long name that kinda destroys the look of the page.

[image: Looking For a Job? Bug]

Comment: I think bugs against the German language should be filed over on https://german.meta.stackexchange.com. :-p

Comment: Developer of Software, the first to be blamed, the Breaker of Loops, the Code Checker, Protector of the Global Namespace and Logger of Errors.

Comment: The job poster needs a smack; why don't they just put spaces between the slashes? Problem solved, intent preserved, I don't have to read yet another "bug" about the layout breaking in some bizarre edge case...

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's curious to me that it doesn't split the line on symbols on its own, honestly. ...Actually, it does on hyphens. Look at the top job posting; it's split on the hyphen in "e-commerce."

Comment: @jpmc26 Always been a problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8186743/215552

Comment: @jpmc26 I guess you wouldn't want an URL to split mid-address... Just a general hypothesis

Comment: I wonder if they look for a [Rhabarberbarbara](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gG62zay3kck).

Comment: `word-wrap: break-all;` will help